# NSVisualEffectView with mask has jagged corners

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, osx-yosemite

In one of the WWDC 2014 talks on the new Yosemite UI, it says to avoid the use of `NSVisualEffectView` in masked layers. Unfortunately my view's layer does have a shape mask, and as a result the visual effect view in it has an ugly jagged edge effect:

[image: gross]

However I know it must be somehow possible to create a masked visual effect view, partly due to 2 reasons:

- The image mask property on `NSVisualEffectView` produces a smooth, anti-alised mask (but requires an unmasked background behind it, and not just an unmasked parent view)
- `NSPopover` and `NSMenu` seem to be able to achieve a smooth mask that changes with dimensions:

[image: Smooth]

[image: Also smooth]

Although it is doubtable as to wether or not they use `NSVisualEffectView`, and not a custom blurred view.

Is there any way I can achieve this smooth mask that doesn't rely on a mask image but rather a path or shape layer?

Comment: Forgive me for asking but why not just use a NSPopover? (especially since Apple say that you should avoid masking NSVisualEffectView)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist its to do with the way that the window has a scrollview thats masked, the arrow below the icon is actually a part of the content view and the text will pass through it. NSPopover doesn't mask its content so anything that tries to render itself within the arrow gets clipped.

Comment: Also, an NSPopover actually creates a slightly different effect than a NSVisualEffectView. Here's an example: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1061741#1061741. Another example: the OS X menubar has the same blur effect as a NSVisualEffectView whereas the NSMenus look more similar to an NSPopover. If you simply open an menu in the menubar then you can easily see the difference between the two effects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a smooth, rounded, volume-like OS X window with NSVisualEffectView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518520/how-to-make-a-smooth-rounded-volume-like-os-x-window-with-nsvisualeffectview)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve this with a `NSWindow` view a while back and I came across this awesome library: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/waythedarkside

It allows you to add a light or dark blur to your view/background. I think this is what you are looking for :)