# How to make a smooth, rounded, volume-like OS X window with NSVisualEffectView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsvisualeffectview

I'm currently trying to make a window that looks like the Volume OS X window:
[image]

To make this, I have my own `NSWindow` (using a custom subclass), which is transparent/titlebar-less/shadow-less, that has a `NSVisualEffectView` inside its contentView. Here's the code of my subclass to make the content view round:

```
- (void)setContentView:(NSView *)aView {
   aView.wantsLayer            = YES;
   aView.layer.frame           = aView.frame;
   aView.layer.cornerRadius    = 14.0;
   aView.layer.masksToBounds   = YES;

   [super setContentView:aView];
}
```

And here's the outcome (as you can see, the corners are grainy, OS X's are way smoother):
[image]

Any ideas on how to make the corners smoother? Thanks

Comment: On iOS, the rounded corners produced by `+[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius:]` use a new, softer rounding curve than rounding the corners of a layer. I wonder if the same is true of `NSBezierPath` on OS X? Here is a deep dive on the new rounding stuff, plus code you can grab and use if you find that it’s not part of `NSBezierPath`: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/code-for-ios-7-rounded-rectangles

Comment: what about `layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = YES;`?

Comment: @BradAllred layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing is specific to iOS, and isn't available on OSX. the OSX equivalent is setting layer.edgeAntialiasingMask, though from trying it does not seem to work on NSVisualEffectView, nor does setting layer.cornerRadius work either.

Comment: FWIW, I've tried a number of variations with no luck so far. @pedro you may want to file a radar on this ( rdar://19589105 here)

Answer (score 24):

## Update for OS X El Capitan

The hack I described in my original answer below is not needed on OS X El Capitan anymore. The `NSVisualEffectView`’s `maskImage` should work correctly there, if the `NSWindow`’s `contentView` is set to be the `NSVisualEffectView` (it’s not enough if it is a subview of the `contentView`).

Here’s a sample project: https://github.com/marcomasser/OverlayTest

---

## Original Answer – Only Relevant for OS X Yosemite

I found a way to do this by overriding a private NSWindow method: `- (NSImage *)_cornerMask`. Simply return an image created by drawing an NSBezierPath with a rounded rect in it to get a look similar to OS X’s volume window.

---

In my testing I found that you need to use a mask image for the NSVisualEffectView *and* the NSWindow. In your code, you’re using the view’s layer’s `cornerRadius` property to get the rounded corners, but you can achieve the same by using a mask image. In my code, I generate an NSImage that is used by both the NSVisualEffectView and the NSWindow:

```
func maskImage(#cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> NSImage {
    let edgeLength = 2.0 * cornerRadius + 1.0
    let maskImage = NSImage(size: NSSize(width: edgeLength, height: edgeLength), flipped: false) { rect in
        let bezierPath = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, xRadius: cornerRadius, yRadius: cornerRadius)
        NSColor.blackColor().set()
        bezierPath.fill()
        return true
    }
    maskImage.capInsets = NSEdgeInsets(top: cornerRadius, left: cornerRadius, bottom: cornerRadius, right: cornerRadius)
    maskImage.resizingMode = .Stretch
    return maskImage
}
```

I then created an NSWindow subclass that has a setter for the mask image:

```
class MaskedWindow : NSWindow {

    /// Just in case Apple decides to make `_cornerMask` public and remove the underscore prefix,
    /// we name the property `cornerMask`.
    @objc dynamic var cornerMask: NSImage?

    /// This private method is called by AppKit and should return a mask image that is used to 
    /// specify which parts of the window are transparent. This works much better than letting 
    /// the window figure it out by itself using the content view's shape because the latter
    /// method makes rounded corners appear jagged while using `_cornerMask` respects any
    /// anti-aliasing in the mask image.
    @objc dynamic func _cornerMask() -> NSImage? {
        return cornerMask
    }

}
```

Then, in my NSWindowController subclass I set up the mask image for the view and the window:

```
class OverlayWindowController : NSWindowController {

    @IBOutlet weak var visualEffectView: NSVisualEffectView!

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        let maskImage = maskImage(cornerRadius: 18.0)
        visualEffectView.maskImage = maskImage
        if let window = window as? MaskedWindow {
            window.cornerMask = maskImage
        }
    }
}
```

I don’t know what Apple will do if you submit an app with that code to the App Store. You’re not actually calling any private API, you’re just overriding a method that happens to have the same name as a private method in AppKit. How should you know that there’s a naming conflict?

Besides, this fails gracefully without you having to do anything. If Apple changes the way this works internally and the method just won’t get called, your window does not get the nice rounded corners, but everything still works and looks *almost* the same.

---

If you’re curious about how I found out about this method:

I knew that the OS X volume indication did what I want to do and I hoped that changing the volume like a madman resulted in noticeable CPU usage by the process that puts that volume indication on screen. I therefore opened Activity Monitor, sorted by CPU usage, activated the filter to only show “My Processes” and hammered my volume up/down keys.

It became clear that `coreaudiod` and something called `BezelUIServer` in `/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/BezelUI/BezelUIServer` did something. From looking at the bundle resources for the latter, it was evident that it is responsible for drawing the volume indication. (Note: that process only runs for a short time after it displays something.)

I then used Xcode to attach to that process as soon as it launched (Debug > Attach to Process > By Process Identifier (PID) or Name…, then enter “BezelUIServer”) and changed the volume again. After the debugger was attached, the view debugger let me take a look at the view hierarchy and see that the window was an instance of a NSWindow subclass called `BSUIRoundWindow`.

Using [`class-dump`](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump) on the binary showed that this class is a direct descendant of NSWindow and only implements three methods, whereas one is `- (id)_cornerMask`, which sounded promising.

Back in Xcode, I used the Object Inspector (right hand side, third tab) to get the address for the window object. Using that pointer I checked what this `_cornerMask` actually returns by printing its description in lldb:

```
(lldb) po [0x108500110 _cornerMask]
<NSImage 0x608000070300 Size={37, 37} Reps=(
    "NSCustomImageRep 0x608000082d50 Size={37, 37} ColorSpace=NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace BPS=0 Pixels=0x0 Alpha=NO"
)>
```

This shows that the return value actually is an NSImage, which is the information I needed to implement `_cornerMask`.

If you want to take a look at that image, you can write it to a file:

```
(lldb) e (BOOL)[[[0x108500110 _cornerMask] TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:(id)[@"~/Desktop/maskImage.tiff" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically:YES]
```

To dig a bit deeper, you can use [Hopper Disassembler](http://www.hopperapp.com) to disassemble `BezelUIServer` and `AppKit` and generate pseudo code to see how the `_cornerMask` is implemented and used to get a clearer picture of how the internals work. Unfortunately, everything in regard to this mechanism is private API.

Comment: Thanks for thoughtful details about exploring.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you. I think this approach gives the best graphical results. I also think the -[NSWindow _cornerMask] API makes a lot of sense, I hope it appears as a public API in a future release.

Comment: Here is an Objective-C implementation of the above to go into an NSWindow subclass: https://gist.github.com/joerick/d52f188b926835b1f655

Comment: Is there something else that needs to be done besides making the `contentView` a masked `NSVisualEffectView` to get the proper behavior on El Capitan? I have an `NSPanel` with a `NSBorderlessWindowMask` and a `clearColor` background and the edges still come out jaggy.

Comment: I just updated the code for Micro Snitch (https://obdev.at/microsnitch) yesterday and it worked fine. I’m using an `NSWindow` with `NSBorderlessWindowMask`, too and the `contentView` is set to `NSVisualEffectView` in Interface Builder. I also created a sample project here: https://github.com/marcomasser/OverlayTest

Comment: Any idea how to display it on top of other windows(i.e. other apps) ? I'm trying to display a such widget when the user is watching fullscreen windows.

Comment: @themihai: You’ll want to take a look at the `NSWindow.level` and `NSWindow.collectionBehavior`properties.

Comment: Unfortunately this technique is broken in macOS Mojave, the mask gets stretched in weird way.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that my sample code on GitHub doesn’t work on the macOS Mojave developer preview. I don’t have time to look into it right now, though 

Answer (score 4):

I remember doing this sort of thing long before `CALayer` was around. You use `NSBezierPath` to make the path.

I don't believe you actually *need* to subclass `NSWindow`. The important bit about the window is to initialize the window with `NSBorderlessWindowMask` and apply the following settings:

```
[window setAlphaValue:0.5]; // whatever your desired opacity is
[window setOpaque:NO];
[window setHasShadow:NO];
```

Then you set the `contentView` of your window to a custom `NSView` subclass with the `drawRect:` method overridden similar to this:

```
// "erase" the window background
[[NSColor clearColor] set];
NSRectFill(self.frame);

// make a rounded rect and fill it with whatever color you like
NSBezierPath* clipPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.frame xRadius:14.0 yRadius:14.0];
[[NSColor blackColor] set]; // your bg color
[clipPath fill];
```

result (ignore the slider):

[image]

**Edit**: If this method is for whatever reason undesirable, can you not simply assign a `CAShapeLayer` as your `contentView`'s `layer` then either convert the above `NSBezierPath` to `CGPath` or just construct as a `CGPath` and assign the path to the layers `path`?

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your answer. The thing is: you're directly drawing a black rounded view, what I want is to have a window and, inside that window, a `NSVisualEffectView` that's round (just like OS X's volume window). Is there a way to "fill" the `NSBezierPath` with that NSVisualEffectView in order to make its borders rounded without all that grain?

Comment: @PedroVieira I don't understand the problem, `NSVisualEffectView` is just an `NSView` subclass, no? cant you just place it as a subview of this view? just pretend *this* view is a "window" (I haven't yet upgraded to Yosemite so i cant test)

Comment: @BradAllred This does not use NSVisualEffectView. When applying a CAShapeLayer you get a jagged edge as shown above in the original question

Answer (score 3):

The "smooth effect" you are referring to is called "Antialiasing".  I did a bit of googling and I think you might be the first person who has tried to round the corners of an NSVisualEffectView.  You told the CALayer to have a border radius, which will round the corners, but you didn't set any other options.  I would try this:

```
layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
layer.edgeAntialiasingMask = kCALayerLeftEdge | kCALayerRightEdge | kCALayerBottomEdge | kCALayerTopEdge;
```

[Anti-alias diagonal edges of CALayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245276/anti-alias-diagonal-edges-of-calayer)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/edgeAntialiasingMask

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've tried what you said and my NSVisualEffect still has those grainy edges. Maybe it's missing another property or something. Here's the code I'm using (_roundView is my NSVisualEffectView): http://pastebin.com/utrMTicj

Answer (score 2):

Despite the limitations of NSVisualEffectView not antialiasing edges, here's a kludgey workaround for now that should work for this application of a floating title-less unresizeable window with no shadow - have a child window underneath that draws out just the edges.

I was able to get mine to look like this:

[image]

by doing the following:

In a controller holding everything:

```
- (void) create {

NSRect windowRect = NSMakeRect(100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 200.0);
NSRect behindWindowRect = NSMakeRect(99.0, 99.0, 202.0, 202.0);
NSRect behindViewRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 202.0, 202.0);

NSRect viewRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 200.0);

window = [FloatingWindow createWindow:windowRect];

behindAntialiasWindow = [FloatingWindow createWindow:behindWindowRect];
roundedHollowView = [[RoundedHollowView alloc] initWithFrame:behindViewRect];

[behindAntialiasWindow setContentView:roundedHollowView];
[window addChildWindow:behindAntialiasWindow ordered:NSWindowBelow];

backingView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

contentView = [[NSVisualEffectView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
[contentView setWantsLayer:NO];
[contentView setState:NSVisualEffectStateActive];
[contentView setAppearance:
 [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight]];
[contentView setMaskImage:[AppDelegate maskImageWithBounds:contentView.bounds]];

[backingView addSubview:contentView];

[window setContentView:backingView];
[window setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
[window orderFront:self];


}

+ (NSImage *) maskImageWithBounds: (NSRect) bounds
{
return [NSImage imageWithSize:bounds.size flipped:YES drawingHandler:^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) {

    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds xRadius:20.0 yRadius:20.0];

    [path setLineJoinStyle:NSRoundLineJoinStyle];
    [path fill];

    return YES;
}];
}
```

RoundedHollowView's drawrect looks like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];
// "erase" the window background
[[NSColor clearColor] set];
NSRectFill(self.frame);

[[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:1.0 alpha:0.7] set];

NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds xRadius:20.0 yRadius:20.0];
path.lineWidth = 2.0;
[path stroke];

}
```

Again, this is a hack and you may need to play with the lineWidth / alpha values depending on the base color you use - in my example if you look really closely or under lighter backgrounds you'll make out the border a bit, but for my own use it feels less jarring than not having any antialiasing.

Keep in mind that the blending mode won't be the same as the native osx yosemite pop-ups like the volume control - those appear to use a different undocumented behindwindow appearance that shows more of a color burn effect.

Comment: looks like the best workaround out there. will give it a try. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

All kudos to Marco Masser for the most neat solution, there're two useful points:

1. For smooth rounded corners to work, the `NSVisualEffectView` must be the root view within view controller.
2. When using the dark material there are still funny light cropped edges that get very apparent on the dark background. Make your window background transparent to avoid this, `window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()`.

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

None of these solutions worked for me on Mojave. However after an hour of research, I found [this amazing repo](https://github.com/lukakerr/NSWindowStyles) which showcases different window designs. One of the solution looks like the OP's desired look. I tried it and it worked with nicely anti-aliased rounded corners and no titlebar artifact remaining. Here is the working code:

```
let visualEffect = NSVisualEffectView()
visualEffect.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
visualEffect.material = .dark
visualEffect.state = .active
visualEffect.wantsLayer = true
visualEffect.layer?.cornerRadius = 16.0

window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
window?.styleMask.remove(.titled)
window?.backgroundColor = .clear
window?.isMovableByWindowBackground = true

window?.contentView?.addSubview(visualEffect)
```

Note at the end the `contentView.addSubview(visualEffect)` instead of `contentView = visualEffect`. This is one of the key to make it work.