# How to reproduce Apple's alert-like views

Tags: ios, uiview

I am struggling the last couple of days to figure out if these alerts are part of `UIKit` or just a private custom view. I don't even know how they properly called. The UI team have asked for an alert that looks like the one appears in Apple's News and Podcast apps. See screenshots below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible dupe?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518520/how-to-make-a-smooth-rounded-volume-like-os-x-window-with-nsvisualeffectview

Comment: Is it possible to create a custom `UIAlertViewController` class?

Comment: @Ssswift not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's code to perform this is not part of UIKit. It will need to be implemented by you! I made a framework to do just this on GitHub called AOModalStatusView (https://github.com/alecdoconnor/AOModalStatusView).

The easiest way to do this would be with a custom view presented modally and with the presentation style set to "over current context" so that what is behind the view shows through. Inside the view create a square that is centered on the view. Give it rounded corners and a specific width and height. In order to get the blurred background you should use Apple's "Visual Effects View with Blur" or "Visual Effects View with Blur and Vibrancy." (https://shrikar.com/ios-development-tutorial-visual-blur-with-uivisualeffectview/)

In the view controller for this view, set a timer shortly in viewDidAppear(..) that will run `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try

Comment: @OutOfBoundsException I don't typically cross-post personal material on SO, but your question inspired me to write a framework for these modal status views. You can find it on GitHub at https://github.com/alecdoconnor/AOModalStatusView with an example of it at https://github.com/alecdoconnor/PuppyParadise

Tutorial will be coming soon too, will update then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my own [StatusAlert](https://github.com/LowKostKustomz/StatusAlert) framework written in Swift. It gives you ability to show Apple system-like alert as well as present the same alert without an image, title or message anywhere in `UIView`.

It is available via Cocoapods and Carthage and supports iPhone X, Safe Areas layout, iPads and allows some customizations.

[image: StatusAlertExample application screenshow]